# How to get textbox text from gridviews current row on click of linkbutton in that row

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Both">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Emailid" HeaderText="EmailId" />
                <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkgettext" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return callme(<%= txtName.ClientID %>);" Text="Gettextboxvalue" ></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function callme(txt) {
            alert(txt);
        }
    </script>
```

Onclick of LinkButton i want to get the value of a textbox from the current row of gridview

Please help me with javascript

Comment: May be [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_val_get) example could fit your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use row data bound as follows
This can be done by jQuery also. But for this first of all the purpose should be clear.
i.e. Weather you want to postback or not etc

```
protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lk = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkgettext");
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtName");
        lk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return callme('" + lk.ClientID + "')");
    }
}
```

and your gridview as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Both"
        OnRowDataBound="gvEmployee_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Emailid" HeaderText="EmailId" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkgettext" runat="server" Text="Gettextboxvalue"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callme(txt) {
            alert(txt);
        }
    </script>
```

or even jquery function as follow

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#gvEmployee a').click(function () {
            alert($(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find("input:text").val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: textbox is editable so i want changed value from javascript and not from code behind

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. The above code just bind client click and nothing else. Have you tried this. I am not changing any value.

Comment: it does help me but what if i have three textboxes in a row and can you please help out with javascript rather than jquery

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your Linkbutton code as Follows:

```
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkgettext" runat="server"  
CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>' 
 OnCommand="Load_Data" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

You can take a **hidden field,** from which you can retrieve value and hidden field would get value from below code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenfield1" runat="server" />
```

On Server Side

```
protected void Grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Load_Data":
        {
            hiddenfield1.value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```